# Unable to share image in android

Tags: android, cordova, android-sharing

I am new in android Java.
I am trying to share an image in android application using Phonegap. I get new class "Share"  as CordovaPlugin, code is follow...

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/www/sharethis.png");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(share, 0);
```

Above code is not working, it showing like this ...

[image]

is think i cant get Exact image file location. 
My file location

[image]

I tried bellow code also, But not work,

```
   String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/assets/www/sharethis.png";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android asset folder is private to your app so you can't share files from there directly. You need to copy the file from assets to a public directory in the filesystem and then send the share intent pointing to the public file